# Do I have to re-buy?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I had a Minecraft account and I wanted to change my skin, but I didn't remember my answers for the question. So I made a new account, but I can only play the demo, even though I had already bought the game. What do I do? Do I have to but it again?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to re-buy the game, just continue using your old account.

If you can't remember the answers, [contact mojang support](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new) with your [transaction ID](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/361380), so they can reset them for you.